# Configurar projeto no tomcat8 Ubuntu Server

Tags: java, aplicação-web, tomcat

Estou tendo dificuldades para configurar o meu projeto no `tomcat8`, utilizo ubuntu server.

Criei um `DNS` ou qual aponta para o meu servidor na porta 8081 e apresenta a pagina inicial do tomcat sem problemas.

Estou com dificuldades para alterar o arquivo `tomcat8/conf/server.xml` para o meu projeto, segue abaixo como está o meu `server.xml`, sou leigo na configuração do `tomcat` e gostaria de saber como direciona um domínio como `meuprojeto.com.br:8081` para a pasta do meu projeto.

```
<Host name="meuprojeto.com.br" appBase="webapps/AcademiaSIG" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> 
    <Context path=""></Context> 
</Host>
```

Já tentei comentar o  que vem por padrão mas continua não redirecionando ao meu projeto.

Abaixo minha arvore de diretórios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deve ser configurar algo mais?

Comment: Você está colocando o war dentro do servidor parado e depois subindo ele?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares como digo antes, sou leigo, o que fiz foi, usar o 'hostmanager' que é exibido inicialmente pelo tomcat e subindo o war, depois disso apenas editei o server.xml para dizer onde estava a pasta do meu projeto que foi criada. Notei que havia um arquivo war dentro da pasta webapps, devo direcionar algo para este arquivo? sempre fiz o restart do tomcat8 para ir vendo as mudanças

Comment: Se o seu servidor está no ar, basta acessar a URL da aplicação que você está fazendo o deploy. Exemplo: sua aplicação tem um contexto "meuApp" e seu tomcat é acessado por localhost:8081, a URL seria localhost:8081//meuApp/suaHomepage

Comment: @WeslleyTavares mas eu quero simplesmente acessar meuprojeto.com.br:8081, sem ter que digita o contexto/modulo